# Form submission error when field value contains spaces or symbols

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having trouble sending an email. The code works just fine if message is only one word. When I add more than one word i.e. with spaces or symbols, it Errors out with "There was an connection error. Please make sure you have internet connection and try again later".

```
- (void)sendAction {

NSString *email = [self.emailTxt text];
NSString *message = [self.messageTxt text];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?email=%@&message=%@", kITSuggestionPage, email, message]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    NSString *title = (!error)? @"Message Sent" : @"Error";
    NSString *message = (!error)? @"Thank you for your Feedback, we hope it will help us to make this product even better." : @"There was an connection error. Please make sure you have internet connection and try again later.";
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];

    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}];


if (email && (email.length > 0)) {
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setObject:email forKey:kITUserEmailKey];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to *URL-escape* your `message` parameter (essentially replacing certain characters that are not allowed in URLs with percent encodings, e.g. `%20` for space).

Example (assuming you're using ARC):

```
NSString *message = [self.messageTxt text];
message = CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef)message, NULL, CFSTR("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
NSURL *url = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add %20 in the place of spaces of the message. If it is working fine now then the problem is with the encoding. Encode your URL before sending request.

```
NSString *urlString = [urlString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding :NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

This will encode the URL.

Comment: Couple of problems with this: 1) Wrong direction – `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` will *decode* the URL, not encode it. 2) Won't work if the message contains the `&` character (allowed in a URL, but breaks the parameter string) 3) Won't work with anything that cannot be represented as ASCII (umlauts etc.)

Comment: Ok, so do you have a suggestion then?

Comment: Anyone have a solution for this, really would appreciate this.